# Setting username and password protection for Xcode IOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, password-protection

How do I set usernames and passwords for my app and they can only be used on one device at a time?
I am making an app that I will be selling as a one-click installation rather than in the app store so I need it to be extra secure. Please let me know what you come up with. I am a beginner programmer so please try to explain in a way that I would understand. Although I have decent knowledge on how to make an app, I would like some help.

P.S. - Some sort of device lock or UDID lock would work too. Whichever way will lock best on one device!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Short answer: there is no way you can stop people from stealing your app. Why are you trying to do it this way?

Comment: If you managed to let users install an App from a web site, please let me know how you did it.

Comment: I have just fifured out a way to make a login page. And the way you would install it from a website is call apple and arrange your app to be ab1click installation rather than in app store purchase. Then they will send you a link where people can download your app. It worked for someone I know.

Comment: I don't believe it, sorry. I would have heard about this. For sure.

Comment: Ill take another look but if that wont work, you can just use zuesmos but then your customers would need to buy a zuesmos account aswell.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the installation worked out (which seems impossible without requesting the user to make a jailbreak), you could setup a server and implement a web socket to check that a given user has only on instance running at any time.

Comment: I am not trying to make it so complex. I would be selling it as a 1 click installation. But rather than hosting a whole server for the app, how can I just setup a login page which will only open to credentials i put in the code for the login page? Thanks again